# Is it ${dy\over dx}\times{dx\over dy} = 1$?

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

I was working with something and have the term ${dy\over dx}\times {dx\over dy}$. In my equality, it must to be $1$, so I try to prove it using the chain rule as follow:

$${dx\over dx} = 1$$
$${dx\over dx} = {d\over dx}(f^{-1}(\ f(x)\ )\ ) = {df^{-1}(f(x))\over df(x)}\times {df(x)\over dx}$$

If we have that $y = f(x)$, so $x = f^{-1}(y)$, then we substitute in the last formula:

$${df^{-1}(f(x))\over df(x)}\times {df\over dx} = {df^{-1}(y)\over dy}\times {dy\over dx}$$
$$ = {dx\over dy}\times {dy\over dx} = 1$$

I should say also,that I was working with functions that are **monotonic for all their domain**. Is this proof correct?

Comment: You need work it locally. To be more precise with hypothesis on the function $y=f(x)$.

Comment: @user1027216 can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Does every function have its inverse?

Comment: @ManjoyDas If it's strictly monotonic, then yes.

Comment: @user1027216 give your edited reply, the function I'm working are monotonic for all the domain. Is it sufficient?

Comment: @DanielMuñoz there is nothing to do with increasing functions. Consider $\log(x)$. It is increasing everywhere except the origin. Or choose any function with a jump discontinuity. So basically it depends on the domain you choose

Comment: @DanielMuñoz in the context of your question, try to think what $dy/dx$  and $dx/dy$ geometrically means.

Comment: @ManjoyDas the origin is not in the domain of $\log (x)$, so I don't see your point

Comment: @DanielMuñoz you can always define a function as you wish. If you don't like $\log(x)$, try $f(x)=x, x<0$ and $f(x)=x+c, c> 0, x\ge 0$

Comment: @ManjoyDas But your new example is not differentiable in all it's domain. Given your first example: $$ {d(\ln (e^x))\over dx} = {d(\ln (e^x))\over d(e^x)}\times {d(e^x)\over dx}$$ $${1\over e^x}\times {e^x} = 1 $$

Comment: @insipidintegrator kinda of, but someone already answer me. Thanks

Comment: @DanielMuñoz look at my comment. I said that monotonicity does not always imply continuity. And my example supports my statement. Inverse of a function exists only if the function is continuous, specifically bijective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the simplest case: Assume you have a diffeomorphism $f: A\to B$ where $A$ and $B$ are open subsets in $\textbf{R}^n$. Then by the chain rule for $x\in A$ and $f(x)=y\in B$:

$$
D(f \circ f^{-1})(y) = (Df)(x) \ \cdot \  D(f^{-1})(y),
$$
the dot is here the matrix multiplication and and $Df$ is the Jacobi matrix of the function $f$, which is a matrix valued function on $A$.

Since $D(f \circ f^{-1}) = D(\textrm{id})=1_{n\times n}$ is the constant, you can see that

$$
(Df)(x) \ \cdot \  D(f^{-1})(y) = 1_{n\times n}.
$$

In 1D, this reads as

$$
f'(x) \cdot (f^{-1})'(f(x)) = 1
$$

or in the Leibnitz notation (which is far less specific)

$$
\frac{\textrm{d}y}{\textrm{d}x}\frac{\textrm{d}x}{\textrm{d}y}=1.
$$

Comment: In a more complicated case, if you have that Df(x) is invertible, then by the inverse function theorem you can find a restriction of f which is a diffeomorphism, and you can apply the steps above. Note that you can also change the order of $f$ and $f^{-1}$, they have interchangeable roles if $f$ is a diffeo.

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Comment: In short, your proof is correct, but often it is important to use the best notation. The Leibnitz notation can get confusing in more complicated proofs. But sometimes it's good if the notation is simple, so there is no golden rule which notation is best, it depends on the specific case.

Comment: Yeah. I understand. I just used it because I'm not well accustomed to linear algebra and matrix calculus or more rigorous theories, but I remember see the identity you use before.

Comment: Also, if you have a strictly monotonic differentiable function, the one you mentioned, that must be a diffeo. But it cannot have constant parts. For the constant parts, this product would be something like $0 \cdot \infty$ that is not really equal to 1, it's more like undefined, and the inverse function doesn't exist (it would be a vertical line, therefore I formally replaced the derivative with infinity).

Comment: What do you mean by "the constant parts", Can you give an example? please

Comment: $f(x) = x$ for $x \geq 0$, else 0. This $f$ is monotonically increasing, but there is $x<=0$, where the function is constant. Or like this in the middle of the domain: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#/media/File:Monotonicity_example1.svg

Comment: Ah okey. Thanks.